# VBA English Excel in Editing/Display/Help Language outputs another language when MonthName (/OR any text extracting function) is used

Tags: vba, excel

As the title suggest i have an `Excel 2010` and i am extracting the month date from a number.

Lets say that the number is at `cell A1` and i am using the `MonthName Function` and a `MsgBox` to test the Language that i get:

```
Sub Extract_Month_Name
    Dim Num as String, Extracted_Month_Name as String

    Num = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value
    Extracted_Month_Name = MonthName(Num,False)
End Sub
```

Now here is the problem! **While i have set the Microsoft Office 2010 Language Preferences:*

- Editing Language has been set to English
- Display Language has been set to English
- Help Language has been set to English

**Still when i use the MonthName Function and use a MsgBox to test this the Month's Name is popping in the Message Box in Greek!!!! How can i change this?**

Comment: _date formats_ depends on _control pannel -> regional settings_ rather that office lang..

Comment: Dear @simoco you have given the correct answer! Thank you so much! Could you please write a few lines so i can mark a correct answer and other new users can see this fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, how your dates/numbers are displayed in Excel depends on *regional settings* rather than language pack for Office you're using.

So, to change regional settings:

1. Click *Start*, and then click *Control Panel*.
2. Click *Date, Time, Language, and Regional Options*, and then click *Regional and Language
   Options*.
3. To change one or more of the individual settings, click *Customize*.

More info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307938/en-us